# How to make Top header and Left header in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to develop a header file like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jm9t14irv1nphc4/layout.png?dl=0)

in which top header and left header would be the same throughout web pages.

I have also created the same,but i am stuck here that how to show data in dynamic contents field.
here is my code to the header.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

main2{
    font-family:myFirstFont1;
    font-size:12px;     
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 17px;
    top: 159px; 
}
.image1 {  }
.image2 {  }
.image3 {  }
.main_divs{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#left{
    width:200px;
    height:750px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:150px;
}
#upper{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    display:inline-block
}
#logo{
    width:352px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
#navigation{  }
#logo,#navigation{
    float:left
}
#inner-nav{
    float:right;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.left_parts{
    height:50%;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin-top:10px;
}
#left-part1{
    background-color:#0093dd;
}
#left-part2{
    background-color:#bfff00;
}

main{
    font-family:myFirstFont1;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size:22px;
}
main1{
    font-family:myFirstFont2;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="upper" class="main_divs">
    <div id="logo"><img  src="images/Shoppin online .png" width="325px" height="50"/></div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <div id="inner-nav">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="35">
    <main2><h3>&nbsp;<a href="index.html">HOME </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; ABOUT US &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTACT &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/twitter.png" width="21" height="17" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/youtube.png" width="20" height="11" />;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/fb.png" width="10" height="21" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/in.png" width="20" height="14" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/p.png" width="16" height="21" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/setting.png" width="19" height="21" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="signup.html">SIGNUP</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php">LOGIN</a></h3>
    </main2>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40"><div class="image2"><input type="text"   value="Search" maxlength="80" style="width:580px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search">
    <div class="text">
    <main1><h2 class="t3"></h2></main1>

    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="35"><div class="image2"><input type="text"   value="Category" name="category" id="category" maxlength="80" style="width:100px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search1"> &nbsp;<input type="text"   value="Product Name" maxlength="80" style="width:120px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search1">&nbsp; <input type="text"   value="Brand" maxlength="80" style="width:100px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search1">&nbsp; <input type="text"   value="Price Range" maxlength="80" style="width:120px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search1">&nbsp; <input type="text"   value="Color" maxlength="80" style="width:85px;height:25px;background-color:#bfff00" class="search1"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="left" class="main_divs">
<div id="left-part1" class="left_parts">Offers</div>
<div id="left-part2" class="left_parts">New Arrivals</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and when i include header.php in any page and insert contents,they are displayed on the top of the webpage and the header.php is displayed.

here is my test.php file in which i am including header.php.

```
<?php
include_once("header/header.php")
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>

tetsdfhgdfkgdfhgdfg




</body>
</html>
```

and the result shows like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xawg0toadt709a9/layout2.png?dl=0).

Comment: You have a doctype declaration in your header file already, so outputting another one after it is of course just nonsense. Same goes for the complete HTML body content that you already have in there as well.

Comment: You need to read a bit about BASICS of templating.

Comment: so i need to delete this sentence:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @DineshKumar The beauty of PHP is that you only have to write the basic HTML once. Everything else can be echoed out in your second php file and included where needed. In other words as CBroe has mentioned your DOCTYPE usage and all other base HTML like head, title, etc. is irrelevant in your header.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You define your page layout in the main file. Let's call it index.php and it's something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"><?php include( "top_header.php" ); ?></div>
  <div id="left_header"><?php include( "left_header.php" ); ?></div>
  <div id="main_content">MAIN CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The top_header.php might be for example:

```
<a href="#link1">Link 1</a> | <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
```

You should not define body, html, doctype in both php files. The main layout and and CSS style, that you define in index.php, is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention here.

In your PHP file you add the same base HTML markup again when you include it in your main file.

in other words:

```
<?php
include_once("header/header.php")
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>

tetsdfhgdfkgdfhgdfg

</body>
</html>
```

All of that is unnecessary. You can simply run the header.php file as the main file (although you might want to rename it), also writing your css etc inline is not such a great idea if you want to maintain neat tidy easy to read source. I would suggest moving it to a new css file and referencing it in the head tags of your php file.

You can also echo out HTML using PHP like this `echo '<h2> this is a test </h2>';`

**To answer your original question**

Here is a start to what you are trying to do.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.ClassContainer
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.titleContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
   
}

.leftContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.contentContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Classcontainer">
    <div class="titleContainer" >    </div>
    <div class="leftContainer ">     </div>
    <div class="contentContainer">   </div>
</div>
```

Read through how to use the include statement in the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple example to do the layouts. So, this is my pretty simple layout:

[image]

It's the same layout that you have shown in the reference image. I just color coded so that you will understand. The above page's HTML code looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Awesome Website!</title>

        <style>
            #wrapper{
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .header_section{
                background-color: red;

                min-height: 50px;
            }

            .left_sidebar_section{
                float: left;
                width: 300px;               
                background-color: rgb(0, 236, 255);

                min-height: 200px;
            }

            .main_contents{
                float: right;
                width: 700px;               
                background-color: rgb(150, 250, 150);

                min-height: 300px;
            }

            #footer{
                background-color: rgb(255, 252, 0);

                min-height: 30px;
            }

            .clear{
                 clear: both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- The whole wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header Section -->
            <div class="header_section">
                Logos, top navigations, etc.. etc...
            </div>
            <!-- /Header Section -->

            <!-- Left Sidebar -->
            <div class="left_sidebar_section">
                left sidebar contents goes here....
            </div>
            <!-- /Left Sidebar -->

            <!-- Main Contents -->
            <div class="main_contents">

                Main content goes here....

            </div>
            <!-- /Main Contents -->

            <div class="clear"></div>


            <!-- Footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                Copyright &copy; blah blah..
            </div>
            <!-- /Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- /The whole wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

---

It has header portion(red color) where you will include the logos, navigation, etc. Then the sidebar(blue color) where you will display the side navigation or advertisements, etc. Then the footer(yellow color) where you will display the credits, footer menus, etc. And the main contents portion(green color), which would be different in each page. Understood the idea?

Now, I have to split them into separate files. Because the header, the left sidebar and the footer are common in all pages! So, am splitting it to three pages - `header.php`, `footer.php` and then the main contents page, say `index.php`. Here's the splitted code:

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Awesome Website!</title>

        <style>
            #wrapper{
                width: 1000px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .header_section{
                background-color: red;

                min-height: 50px;
            }

            .left_sidebar_section{
                float: left;
                width: 300px;               
                background-color: rgb(0, 236, 255);

                min-height: 200px;
            }

            .main_contents{
                float: right;
                width: 700px;               
                background-color: rgb(150, 250, 150);

                min-height: 300px;
            }

            #footer{
                background-color: rgb(255, 252, 0);

                min-height: 30px;
            }

            .clear{
                 clear: both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- The whole wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header Section -->
            <div class="header_section">
                Logos, top navigations, etc.. etc...
            </div>
            <!-- /Header Section -->

            <!-- Left Sidebar -->
            <div class="left_sidebar_section">
                left sidebar contents goes here....
            </div>
            <!-- /Left Sidebar -->
```

**footer.php**

```
            <div class="clear"></div>


            <!-- Footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                Copyright &copy; blah blah..
            </div>
            <!-- /Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- /The whole wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

            <!-- Main Contents -->
            <div class="main_contents">

                Main content goes here....

            </div>
            <!-- /Main Contents -->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

---

See how I splitted it? Now, if I want to include a contact page, say `contact.php`, I would simply copy the contents of the above `index.php` and adds the contents in a new file and save it as `contact.php`! Eg:

**contact.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

            <!-- Main Contents -->
            <div class="main_contents">

                Enter your contact details... blah blah...

            </div>
            <!-- /Main Contents -->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

That's all! Pretty simple isn't it? :) Feel free to ask if you have doubt.